# Type inconsistency occurs when using range on string

Tags: string, go

The following code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    str := "s"
    for i, v := range str {
        fmt.Printf("type of s[%v]: %T\n", i, str[i])
        fmt.Printf("type of v: %T\n", v)
    }
}
```

yields:

```
type of s[0]: uint8
type of v: int32
```

In most languages, strings consist of signed or unsigned 8-bit characters. Why is `v` `int32` instead of `uint8`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [For statements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements)
>
> For statements with range clause
>
> For a string value, the "range" clause iterates over the Unicode code
>   points in the string starting at byte index 0. On successive
>   iterations, the index value will be the index of the first byte of
>   successive UTF-8-encoded code points in the string, and the second
>   value, of type rune, will be the value of the corresponding code
>   point. If the iteration encounters an invalid UTF-8 sequence, the
>   second value will be 0xFFFD, the Unicode replacement character, and
>   the next iteration will advance a single byte in the string.

---

There is no inconsistency.

In Go, `rune`, a Unicode code point, is an alias for `int32`.

Go is not an old language that is limited to the ASCII character set. Like most [all?] modern languages, Go uses Unicode.

---

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    helloworld := "Hello, 世界"
    fmt.Println(helloworld)
    for i, r := range helloworld {
        fmt.Println(i, r, string(r))
    }
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/Q_iEzdlGxLu

Output:

```
Hello, 世界
0 72 H
1 101 e
2 108 l
3 108 l
4 111 o
5 44 ,
6 32  
7 19990 世
10 30028 界
```

---

[The Go Blog: Strings, bytes, runes and characters in Go](https://blog.golang.org/strings)

[The Unicode Consortium](http://unicode.org/)